# My MongoDB server crashes with Invariant failure

Tags: python, php, mongodb, docker

I have a PHP code and Python code that accesses this MongoDB server in production running on Docker. But every now and then, the MongoDB container restarts with this log, and I am unable to find what is the root cause of this random crash. This is a standalone server with no replica sets. I tried posting in MongoDB Developer Community, and raised a ticket in their Jira, so far, no responses.

Here is the crash log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T06:30:50.517+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":22,"message":{"ts_sec":1693981850,"ts_usec":517620,"thread":"1:0x7f9c42ef9640","session_name":"WT_SESSION.get_key","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__wt_txn_context_prepare_check:19:not permitted in a prepared transaction","error_str":"Invalid argument","error_code":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T06:30:50.517+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23083,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Invariant failure","attr":{"expr":"cursor->get_key(cursor, &recordId)","error":"BadValue: 22: Invalid argument","file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp","line":2552}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T06:30:50.517+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23084,   "ctx":"conn3","msg":"\n\n***aborting after invariant() failure\n\n"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T06:30:50.517+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"conn3","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"Got signal: 6 (Aborted).\n"}}
```

For full log of the multiple crash incidents: https://s3.selfmade.ninja/crashlog/mongo-crash-logs.zip

I have `featureCompatiblityVersion` set to 6.0 and I am running on MongoDB 6.0.9 server. I tried to move up to MongoDB 7.0 also, but nothing changed. I tried upgrading the PHP MongoDB drivers to latest version, no use, the container restarts every now and then.

Here are the things I tried:

- I dumped all data and moved them to 6.0, 6.0.9, 7.0 servers, crash happens everywhere
- I updated the MongoDB drivers for PHP and Python
- I repaired the database with `--repair` and it said nothing is wrong
- I upgraded the database with `--upgrade` and it did nothing, still crashing

This restart is putting the production server stalled for over 10 seconds in random times and I have no clue what to do from here.

**Update 1:**

I have increased the verbosity of the MongoDB logs and found these interesting among the pile of logs it generated at level 3.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T07:24:05.844+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":51803,   "ctx":"conn1023","msg":"Slow query","attr":{"type":"command","ns":"vpn.session","command":{"find":"session","filter":{"access_token":"<hidden>"},"limit":1,"$db":"vpn","lsid":{"id":{"$uuid":"a44079c4-ebd9-4126-8aaf-bf439aecda11"}}},"planSummary":"COLLSCAN","keysExamined":0,"docsExamined":145708,"cursorExhausted":true,"numYields":145,"nreturned":1,"queryHash":"CAEA5ECC","planCacheKey":"CAEA5ECC","queryFramework":"classic","reslen":384,"locks":{"FeatureCompatibilityVersion":{"acquireCount":{"r":146}},"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":146}},"Mutex":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}},"storage":{},"remote":"172.18.0.1:57968","protocol":"op_msg","durationMillis":30}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T07:24:05.844+00:00"},"s":"D2", "c":"QUERY",    "id":22783,   "ctx":"conn1023","msg":"Received interrupt request for unknown op","attr":{"opId":296291,"knownOps":[]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T07:24:05.844+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"-",        "id":5127803, "ctx":"conn1023","msg":"Released the Client","attr":{"client":"conn1023"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T07:24:05.844+00:00"},"s":"D3", "c":"-",        "id":5127801, "ctx":"conn1023","msg":"Setting the Client","attr":{"client":"conn1023"}}
```

We run Wireguard Manager in PHP and a new intern moved it from MySQL to MongoDB recently. He didn't set any keys for this `vpn.session` collection, and I believe everytime an access token is looked up, its considered slow query and the above log says the same connection context has some invalid operation, and I believe this may be linked to the assertion error the MongoDB is throwing, still I wonder how can it crash the MongoDB server. The collection has millions of documents without index, and that may be the cause of the race condition which threw the Invariant Failure.

I am not sure about this Hypothesis, but I am gonna build some index in that collection and gonna watch for a while and see if the crash is gonna happen again.

Comment: Seems like bug in your code not in the mongodb server.

Comment: I just don't know where to look, the log is not informative, can you help me filter out since the code base is quite big? Is there a way to make MongoDB print more logs?

Comment: @Manusha even if something is wrong with my code, how can it crash the MongoDB server itself?

Comment: `src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp","line":2552` - have you investigated that?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I tried to, but it is all internal operations and didn’t made much sense. But I made an update to the question with my recent findings.

Comment: @Sibidharan  In your log files, Search for  :"W", and you may find come Warning clues meant to assist with your situation.